# Ubuntu get stuck on Restart or any other event, Force switch off leads to a broken boot loader

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I Have Ubuntu 12.04 installed in Lenovo ThnkPad S540. nce in a while ( 3 times for the last week), Ubuntu got stuck when I restart or even when im working (pulled out extended monitor). Then when I use the power button to shut the computer and start it back it takes me to grub. Then I need to use boot fix usb and fix the whole thing. Any idea what is causing ubuntu to break the boot loader so easily. What am i missing ??

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with different HW (acer travelmate 115). I was quite desperate and then found a discussion. The problem was with switching on (booting) and off. I had tried the different ubuntu versions. Finally, I just changed the method of booting in Bios and since then, it worked smoothly without any problem. The right booting method was UEFI (not Legacy).